# Confirmation URL Keeps Changing, Assuming this causes issues with current code

Tags: python

In a nutshell I want to do something that's seen here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UtNYzv8gLbs Submitting information while also using a name list, making it an email, and sending a password. The issue is, when information is submitted to the form I'm filling out, it redirects you to the a confirmation link saying "Your info has been submitted", but the URL has a random string of characters at the end. I'm curious if there's an alternative, if the URL changes everytime information is submitted, is it safe to assume that any other attempts to use that URL would be blocked due to duplicate submissions?  I'll paste the code within that video. I'm rather new to this so any sort of guidance would be amazing.

I'll just drop the Source code links but ofc they'll be provided due to forum rules

https://github.com/engineer-man/youtube/blob/master/033/scam.py
https://github.com/engineer-man/youtube/blob/master/033/names.json

Though my knowledge is limited, I tried Selenium, which may be the solution but I'm unsure.

```
import requests
import os
import random
import string
import json

chars = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + '!@#$%^&*()'
random.seed = (os.urandom(1024))

url = 'http://craigslist.pottsfam.com/index872dijasydu2iuad27aysdu2yytaus6d2ajsdhasdasd2.php'

names = json.loads(open('names.json').read())

for name in names:
    name_extra = ''.join(random.choice(string.digits))

    username = name.lower() + name_extra + '@yahoo.com'
    password = ''.join(random.choice(chars) for i in range(8))

    requests.post(url, allow_redirects=False, data={
        'auid2yjauysd2uasdasdasd': username,
        'kjauysd6sAJSDhyui2yasd': password
    })

    print 'sending username %s and password %s' % (username, password)
```

In the end, I'd like to be able to submit information (In this case, and email and a password) and then have it submitted. To my knowledge this won't work due to the confirmation URL changing everytime new info is submitted.